# Changing xaxis label from echarts library

Tags: javascript, charts, echarts

```
var data = [];
var dataCount = 10;
var startTime = +new Date();
var categories = ['categoryA', 'categoryB', 'categoryC'];
var types = [
    {name: 'JS Heap', color: '#7b9ce1'},
    {name: 'Documents', color: '#bd6d6c'},
    {name: 'Nodes', color: '#75d874'},
    {name: 'Listeners', color: '#e0bc78'},
    {name: 'GPU Memory', color: '#dc77dc'},
    {name: 'GPU', color: '#72b362'}
];

// Generate mock data
echarts.util.each(categories, function (category, index) {
    var baseTime = startTime;
    for (var i = 0; i < dataCount; i++) {
        var typeItem = types[Math.round(Math.random() * (types.length - 1))];
        var duration = Math.round(Math.random() * 10000);
        data.push({
            name: typeItem.name,
            value: [
                index,
                baseTime,
                baseTime += duration,
                duration
            ],
            itemStyle: {
                normal: {
                    color: typeItem.color
                }
            }
        });
        baseTime += Math.round(Math.random() * 2000);
    }
});

function renderItem(params, api) {
    var categoryIndex = api.value(0);
    var start = api.coord([api.value(1), categoryIndex]);
    var end = api.coord([api.value(2), categoryIndex]);
    var height = api.size([0, 1])[1] * 0.6;

    var rectShape = echarts.graphic.clipRectByRect({
        x: start[0],
        y: start[1] - height / 2,
        width: end[0] - start[0],
        height: height
    }, {
        x: params.coordSys.x,
        y: params.coordSys.y,
        width: params.coordSys.width,
        height: params.coordSys.height
    });

    return rectShape && {
        type: 'rect',
        shape: rectShape,
        style: api.style()
    };
}


option = {
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function (params) {
            return params.marker + params.name + ': ' + params.value[3] + ' ms';
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Profile',
        left: 'center'
    },
    dataZoom: [{
        type: 'slider',
        filterMode: 'weakFilter',
        showDataShadow: false,
        top: 400,
        height: 10,
        borderColor: 'transparent',
        backgroundColor: '#e2e2e2',
        handleIcon: 'M10.7,11.9H9.3c-4.9,0.3-8.8,4.4-8.8,9.4c0,5,3.9,9.1,8.8,9.4h1.3c4.9-0.3,8.8-4.4,8.8-9.4C19.5,16.3,15.6,12.2,10.7,11.9z M13.3,24.4H6.7v-1.2h6.6z M13.3,22H6.7v-1.2h6.6z M13.3,19.6H6.7v-1.2h6.6z', // jshint ignore:line
        handleSize: 20,
        handleStyle: {
            shadowBlur: 6,
            shadowOffsetX: 1,
            shadowOffsetY: 2,
            shadowColor: '#aaa'
        },
        labelFormatter: ''
    }, {
        type: 'inside',
        filterMode: 'weakFilter'
    }],
    grid: {
        height:300
    },
    xAxis: {
        min: startTime,
        scale: true,
        axisLabel: {
            formatter: function (val) {
                return Math.max(0, val - startTime) + ' ms';
            }
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        data: categories
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'custom',
        renderItem: renderItem,
        itemStyle: {
            normal: {
                opacity: 0.8
            }
        },
        encode: {
            x: [1, 2],
            y: 0
        },
        data: data
    }]
};
```

Hi, everyone!! I am working on the echarts library, the only thing i want to change data is the axisLabel from Xaxis part.

What i mean is, for example, "2019-11-5, 2019-11-6...."and so on. So, i hope someone can help me out, thank you so much!!!

Hi, everyone!! I am working on the echarts library, the only thing i want to change data is the axisLabel from Xaxis part.

What i mean is, for example, "2019-11-5, 2019-11-6...."and so on. So, i hope someone can help me out, thank you so much!!!

Comment: Sorry for posting two same paragraph

Comment: Which type of chart are you working within echarts ?

Comment: I using Gannt Chart, would like to view the chart from original website?

Comment: can you send the link to that chart

Comment: Please help me how to change x coordinates to the timeline format. Like '2019 11-11', '2020 11-12'. Thank you.

Comment: https://gallery.echartsjs.com/editor.html?c=xGeNfEsuhT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create an array of dates like

```
var dates = ['2019-11-5','2019-10-3','2019-2-2','2019-1-4','2019-12-5'];
```

then in xAxis -> axisLabel return date

```
axisLabel: {
        formatter: function (val,index) {
            return dates[index];
        }
    }
```

Comment: ok, thank you so much!! You help me a lot, but there is more things that i ask you to help. How to one item correspond to a number? For example, 2016-11-12 to GPU s item, then 2016-11-13 to listeners item and so on. I really appreciated, please one more last things, thank you so much!!

Comment: Another wrong type please help me one more last things

Comment: first item in dates array corresponds to first item in types array and so on

Comment: YES, exactly. Can you help me? This is last question

Comment: Like gpu to 2019, listeners to 2020. Each dates related to the paticular item

Comment: just like one column for one dates